# $f(x) : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is defined for real numbers from the closed interval $[0, 1]$

Tags: calculus, discrete-mathematics

Hello I am preparing for a math exam and I have the following preparation task:

The function $f(x) : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is defined for real numbers from the closed interval [0, 1] and has the following properties:

- $f\left(\dfrac{x}{3}\right) = \dfrac{1}{2}f(x)$
- $f(1-x) = 1 - f(x)$
- The function is non-diminishing, ie. if $x_1 \lt x_2$ then $f(x_1) \le f(x_2)$

To be found:

$f\left(\dfrac{2021}{2022}\right) = \text{?}$

I have 5 different possible answers, but I have no idea how to approach this problem. It is a little bit confusing for me what f(x/3) means to be equal to 1/2f(x)

The options are:

- $f\left(\dfrac{2021}{2022}\right) = \dfrac{1}{2}$
- $f\left(\dfrac{2021}{2022}\right) = \dfrac{127}{128}$
- $f\left(\dfrac{2021}{2022}\right) = \dfrac{1}{1024}$
- $f\left(\dfrac{2021}{2022}\right) = \dfrac{2019}{2020}$
- $f\left(\dfrac{2021}{2022}\right) = \dfrac{2019}{2048}$

Any help on how to solve the equation are welcome, because I have similar tasks and I need to find the way how to solve them.

PS: If I am not wrong I can get the properties to:

- $f(x) = 2f\left(\dfrac{x}{3}\right)$
- $f(1 - x) + f(x) = 1$

but this also does not help

Comment: Welcome to MSE! To get a feel for this function, see if you can determine $f(1/4)$ and $f(3/4)$ (the two properties of your function give you two different equations relating them). It will also be useful to take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function

Comment: As @Warter noticed: $f$ agrees with Cantor-Lebesgue function outside the Cantor ternary set. If it is assumed to be continuous, then $f$ agrees completely with Cantor-Lebesgue.

Comment: Please don't edit your question to something entirely different. If you have a new question, please just ask a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substituting $x=0$ in $f(x) = 2f\left(\dfrac{x}{3}\right)$ we get $f(0)=0$. Now substituting $x=0$ in $f(1 - x) + f(x) = 1$ imply $f(1)=1$.

Again, $1=f(1)=2f\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)$, thus, $f\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)=\frac{1}{2}$. The equality $f(1 - x) + f(x) = 1$ imply $f\left(1-\frac{1}{3}\right)+f\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)=1$, hence, $f\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)=\frac{1}{2}$.

Since $f$ is increasing, $\frac{1}{3} \le x \le \frac{2}{3} \Rightarrow \frac{1}{2} = f\left(\frac{1}{3}\right) \le f(x) \le f\left(\frac{2}{3}\right) = \frac{1}{2} \Rightarrow f(x)=\frac{1}{2}$.

If $x \le \frac{1}{3}$, then $f(x) = \frac{1}{2}f(3x)$.

Thus, $\frac{1}{3^2} \le x \le \frac{2}{3^2} \Rightarrow \frac{1}{3} \le 3x \le \frac{2}{3} \Rightarrow f(x)=\frac{1}{2} f(3x) = \frac{1}{2^2}$. By induction, we can show that $\frac{1}{3^n} \le x \le \frac{2}{3^n} \Rightarrow f(x) = \frac{1}{2^n}$.

Since, $\frac{1}{3^7} \le \frac{1}{2022} \le \frac{2}{3^7} \Rightarrow   f\left(\frac{1}{2022}\right) = \frac{1}{2^7} = \frac{1}{128}$.

By $f(1-x) = 1 - f(x)$, we find that
$$
f\left(\frac{2021}{2022}\right) = f\left(1-\frac{1}{2022}\right) = 1 - f\left(\frac{1}{2022}\right) = 1-\frac{1}{128} = \frac{127}{128}.$$